# My code broke jsbin and repl.it?

Tags: javascript

while (re)doing this tutorial, http://reactivex.io/learnrx/, I find that both repl.it and jsbin.com reject functional javascript like this.

```
movieLists.
        concatMap(function(category) {
            return category.videos.map(function(video){

                return video.boxarts
                    .reduce(function(acc,cur){
                        return (acc.width*acc.height)<(cur.width*cur.height) ? acc:cur
                    }).map(function(boxart){
                        return {id:video.id, title:video.title}
                    });


            })
        })
```

results in

```
"TypeError: video.boxarts.reduce(...).map is not a function
    at dihuwo.js:105:24
    at Array.map (native)
    at dihuwo.js:100:36
    at dihuwo.js:24:14
    at Array.map (native)
    at Array.concatMap (dihuwo.js:18:3)
    at dihuwo.js:99:3
    at dihuwo.js:113:3
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.35.5.min.js:1:13616
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.35.5.min.js:1:10537"
```

why does the code [here on jsbin](https://jsbin.com/dihuwo/edit?js,console) fail, while the repl [here](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/) accepts it as legit?

What silly thing am I missing? I repeat... the code is passing on the tutorial page. It's just impossible so far to test on any other repl.

P.S. All helper functions, such as concatMap, are defined above this code, so that's not the problem.

Comment: Hint #1: what does your `reduce()` return? Hint #2: it's not an array.

Comment: To make things more transparent it's recommended to always set the initial value of the `reduce` as the unit value of the type you're expecting it to return. If you expect an array - initialise it with `[]`.

Comment: it returns an object, which I did not test for 'arrayness'. Here is the official answer from the site, and it looks like it returns an object too, and that map is happy with it (which makes no sense, I know) https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/lkj2dewi3ofvkgc/vh-6d1xm.jpg

Comment: So how the `.map` function is supposed to appear in that object? What is `video.boxarts` and how `video.boxarts.reduce` is defined?

Comment: video.boxarts is an array of objects... So we have code that shouldn't work, passing on http://reactivex.io/learnrx

Comment: Well, their implementation of `reduce` does not match to `Array.prototype.reduce`. They always return an array, see "Exercise 16: Implement reduce()". And they override the native implementation with their own (which is dirty and misleading).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because in that tutorial they override `Array.prototype.reduce`.

Their implementation works differently to the standard one and it always returns an array.

Generally it's a bad practice to do so and must be avoided.

Comment: I remember now... Lots of complaints about this set of exercises. And now there's one more. So what is the professional way to go about this? Lodash? Or something like ramda.js?

Comment: "professional" is a speculative word :-) I personally use both lodash and ramda